# Flume running failed in Linux

Tags: linux, flume

when I installed flume into Linux.I am getting some warning while running flume
I  followed this procedure to install a flume .

```
>> sudo tar -xvf flume-ng-1.1.0-cdh4.0.1\(1\).tar.gz
>> export PATH=/home/hduser/downloads/flume-1.1.0- cdh4.0.1/bin:$PATH
>> $ sudo cp conf/flume-conf.properties.template conf/flume.conf
```

for running the flume I used this command

```
>> $ bin/flume-ng agent -n agent -f conf/flume.conf
```

but it is showing some warnings

```
hadoopmaster@HadoopMaster:/home/hduser/downloads/flume-ng$ sudo bin/flume-ng agent -n agent -f conf/flume.conf
Warning: No configuration directory set! Use --conf <dir> to override.
Warning: JAVA_HOME not set!
+ exec /usr/bin/java -Xmx20m -cp '/home/hduser/downloads/flume-ng/lib/*' -Djava.library.path= org.apache.flume.node.Application -n agent -f conf/flume.conf
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.flume.lifecycle.LifecycleSupervisor).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to get output from the log4j appender then you need to add -c conf to your command line. For example:

```
export JAVA_HOME=... # recommended to set JAVA_HOME properly
./bin/flume-ng agent -c conf -f conf/flume.conf -n agent
```

Comment: I do have `-c` in my command, still theres issue `flume-ng agent --conf /opt/flume/conf/ -f /opt/flume/conf/flume.conf -Dflume.root.logger=DEBUG -n supply_agent`

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the Java_Home path in `flume-env.sh` file

export Java_Home = `/user/lib/jvm/java_version_name`

Answer (score 0):

Please set HADOOP_HOME env variable.